# Draw tree from preorder and postorder traversal without any assumptions on tree shape

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, tree, binary-tree

In my exam, I faced the following question:

[image]

`(a)` was very easy, but, for `(b)`, I am totally confused. What does is mean to make no assumptions? If I do not assume it is a binary tree how can I solve it (because pre-order and post-order are related to BST)? Without assuming it is a BST, I don't know how to start?

Could you please guide me?

Comment: Sorry but I did not get what u mean

Comment: Don't forget to help me:)

Comment: Compare it to the first question, part `(a)`: in `(b)` you can't assume that it's a balanced binary tree. You just have to deduce the in-order representation given the pre- and post-order lists. I think that they're trying to say it's not necessarily alphabetical or balanced.

Comment: so do you mean I can use Bst structure but it does not necessarily be Balace Bst?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

b) Well, these orders seen consistent with a binary tree ordering:

```
V W B C Y Z N A M L P
C B Z N Y W M P L A V
```

First, note the root is V because it's both first in the preorder and last in the postorder:

```
V W B C Y Z N A M L P
  C B Z N Y W M P L A V
```

Then look at W and A, they are, respectively, they are first left child and the last right child of the root. A in the preorder marks the place where the traversal transitions from the left subtree of the root to the right subtree of the root. W in the postorder marks the same place. Note that that when you split the traversals, A and W are adjacent positions:

```
V W B C Y Z N    A M L P
  C B Z N Y W    M P L A V
```

Now you are left to solve the same problem for the sequences:

```
W B C Y Z N    
C B Z N Y W
```

and

```
A M L P
M P L A
```

For example, the next step for the first sequence would be:

```
W B C    Y Z N    
  C B    Z N Y W
```

Hope this helps.